# UNIX - why doesn't $# include the command (thus always being >= 1)?

Tags: bash, unix, arguments

It's kind of hard to search for an answer on this since `$#` doesn't seem to go through properly on search engines. I was curious as to why `argv` typically includes the command name itself, while `$#` doesn't.

To make it clearer, if I have a script called testing.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $#
```

`./testing.sh` returns `0` and not `1`. Why?

Comment: BTW, in the future, you might tag such questions `sh` rather than `bash` -- as it's something present in POSIX sh, a standard bash mostly attempts to comply with (as do ksh, ash/dash, and many others). Bash-tagged questions tend to only get looked at by folks who know bash, whereas folks handy with ksh or POSIX sh itself without being familiar with bash extensions will often also be looking at questions tagged sh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bash` is following the [POSIX specification for `$#`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02):

> Expands to the decimal number of positional parameters. The command name (parameter 0) shall not be counted in the number given by '#' because it is a special parameter, not a positional parameter.

The shell's interface to the arguments is simply different from C's. In `bash` terms, you might define

```
argv=( "$0" "$@")
argc=${#argv[@]}
```

since the shell (sensibly) separates the command name from the command's arguments.